# Making a movie from the url using ffmpeg and phantomjs

Tags: video, ffmpeg, phantomjs

Im Taking screen shots from a url, using phantomjs using the setIntreval function (25 right now) and then piping the output to the ffmpeg (Using the frame rate -r 24).
Here is the Code. ffmpeg.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };

page.open('http://ewoken.github.io/Leaflet.MovingMarker/', function () {
  setInterval(function() {
    page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: "png" });
  }, 25);
});
```

Then I run the script using this.

```
phantomjs ffmpeg.js | ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 24 -t 10 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Like In the command Im getting the 10 sec video with the page, But Its all speeding up fast first and completely freezes with a last frame.

Can you guys help me, with a work around, enabling me to record the page , AS IS ? Like if there is a 3000 delay animation in the movie, It should appear like real in the movie, like smooth and in real time.

Thank you guys. Stuck on this for a long time now.

Cheers,

Comment: PhantomJS isn't able probably to keep making png screenshots of this size in real time (unless you got VERY fast computer). Consider making framerate lower, saving in jpg, using lower resolution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to have ffmpeg with the `--enable-x11grab` option, you need to compile it.

```
# example:
https://gist.github.com/holms/7009218
https://soledadpenades.com/2010/04/26/unknown-input-or-output-format-x11grab-ubuntu/
```

configuration:

```
--prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-libvorbis
```

We need to use [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/), it's not a headless browser, but scriptable as well:

```
cd /root; \
wget http://download.slimerjs.org/releases/0.10.1/slimerjs-0.10.1.zip && unzip slimerjs-0.10.1.zip && \
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-49.0.2.tar.bz2 && \
tar -vxjf firefox-49.0.2.tar.bz2 && \
ln -sf /root/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/ -v && \
ln -sf /root/slimerjs-0.10.1/slimerjs /usr/local/bin/ -v
```

For slimerjs, we need to install the following `snap.js` script:
`rm -f snap.js; nano snap.js; chmod +x snap.js; clear`

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {width: 1024,height: 768};
page.open('http://ewoken.github.io/Leaflet.MovingMarker/', function() {
page.evaluate(function () {window.focus();});
//  page.render('github.png');
//  phantom.exit();
});
```

Now, we need to install `x virtual frame buffer` and some libraries for firefox:

```
aptitude update; aptitude install Xvfb libgtk-3-0 libasound2 libdbus-glib-1-2 -y
```

Now we need to add new virtual display 1.1:

```
pkill [X,x]vfb; pkill nw; Xvfb :1 -screen 1 1440x900x24 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Try to run `firefox` without any option, to make sure that no additional library needed (it's normal if there will be some errors in the output):

```
killall firefox; export DISPLAY=:1.1; firefox
```

Then, we can use the script:

```
killall firefox; rm -f ouput2.mp4; \
sleep 5; export DISPLAY=:1.1; export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/root/firefox/firefox; \
slimerjs snap.js & \
sleep 3; \
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60 -video_size 1024x768 -i :1.1 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 10000k ouput2.mp4
```

I've got this video:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBndDJ0Y1c5THBKWkk

**Note: if you are using 32-Bit Linux, you need to replace the link:**

```
https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-49.0.2.tar.bz2
```

With the following:

```
https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-49.0.2.tar.bz2
```

Comment: I've worked on Xen DomU without an X server. OS Debian 8 Jessie, 64-Bit.

Comment: [ffmpeg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnOEtuR0txSWVwX1E) | 
[x264](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBneWRRVVJqV2dIOTg)